# How to (ignore|keep going) a gant-build in case of compile errors?

Tags: ant, gant

Does anybody know how I can run a gant build which ignores build errors? Something like ant and make are doing with the '-k' or '-keep-going' switch.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -k flag hasn't been added yet to gant, afaik. You can submit a feature request for it here:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GANT